# Test a controller with success() and error ()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to work out the best way to unit test success and error callbacks in controllers. I am able to mock out service methods, as long as the controller only uses the default $q functions such as 'then' (see the example below). I'm having an issue when the controller responds to a 'success' or 'error' promise. (Sorry if my terminology is not correct).

Here is an example controller \ service

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers');

myControllers.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', 'myService',
  function ($scope, myService) {

      var id = 1;
      $scope.loadData = function () {
          myService.get(id).then(function (response) {
              $scope.data = response.data;
          });
      };

      $scope.loadData2 = function () {
          myService.get(id).success(function (response) {
              $scope.data = response.data;
          }).error(function(response) {
              $scope.error = 'ERROR';
          });
      }; 
  }]);


cocoApp.service('myService', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        function get(id) {
            return $http.get('/api/' + id);
        }
    }
]);
```

I have the following test

```
'use strict';

describe('SimpleControllerTests', function () {

    var scope;
    var controller;
    var getResponse = { data: 'this is a mocked response' };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($q, $controller, $rootScope, $routeParams){

        scope = $rootScope;
        var myServiceMock = {
            get: function() {}
        };

        // setup a promise for the get
        var getDeferred = $q.defer();
        getDeferred.resolve(getResponse);
        spyOn(myServiceMock, 'get').andReturn(getDeferred.promise);

        controller = $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope, myService: myServiceMock });
    }));


    it('this tests works', function() {
        scope.loadData();
        expect(scope.data).toEqual(getResponse.data);
    });

    it('this doesnt work', function () {
        scope.loadData2();
        expect(scope.data).toEqual(getResponse.data);
    });
});
```

The first test passes and the second fails with the error "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'success'". I get that in this instance that getDeferred.promise
does not have a success function. Okay here is the question, what is a nice way to write this test so that I can test the 'success', 'error' & 'then' conditions of a mocked service ?

I'm starting to think that I should avoid the use of success() and error() in my controllers...

**EDIT**

So after thinking about this some more, and thanks to the detailed answer below, **I've come to the conclusion that the handling the success and error callbacks in the controller is bad.** As HackedByChinese mentions below success\error is syntactic sugar that is added by $http. So, in actual fact, by trying to handle success \ error I am letting $http concerns leak into my controller, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid by wrapping the $http calls in a service. The approach I'm going to take is to change the controller not to use success \ error:

```
myControllers.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', 'myService',
  function ($scope, myService) {

      var id = 1;
      $scope.loadData = function () {
          myService.get(id).then(function (response) {
              $scope.data = response.data;
          }, function (response) {
              $scope.error = 'ERROR';
          });
      };
  }]);
```

This way I can test the error \ success conditions by calling resolve() and reject() on the deferred object:

```
'use strict';

describe('SimpleControllerTests', function () {

    var scope;
    var controller;
    var getResponse = { data: 'this is a mocked response' };
    var getDeferred;
    var myServiceMock;

    //mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));
    //mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($q, $controller, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

        scope = $rootScope;
        myServiceMock = {
            get: function() {}
        };
        // setup a promise for the get
        getDeferred = $q.defer();
        spyOn(myServiceMock, 'get').andReturn(getDeferred.promise);
        controller = $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope, myService: myServiceMock });  
    }));

    it('should set some data on the scope when successful', function () {
        getDeferred.resolve(getResponse);
        scope.loadData();
        scope.$apply();
        expect(myServiceMock.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.data).toEqual(getResponse.data);
    });

    it('should do something else when unsuccessful', function () {
        getDeferred.reject(getResponse);
        scope.loadData();
        scope.$apply();
        expect(myServiceMock.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.error).toEqual('ERROR');
    });
});
```

Comment: With Angular Mocks (which you are already using), you can use `$httpBackend` to set up expectations for http calls and specify how they should respond, then you can `flush` them to complete your test synchronously. Why not go that route? See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that helps. In this case I'm trying to unit test the controller so I'm completely mocking out the service which is making the $http calls. In this example there is no code that calls $http as the mock service is injected into the controller.

Comment: thanks for teaching me to separate out HTTP functionality from controller, it doesn't make sense to have it in there now that I've seen this

Comment: Also just to add, in Jasmine 2.3.1 you need to use `and.returnValue` on your spy, instead of `andReturn`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As someone had mentioned in a deleted answer, `success` and `error` are syntactic sugar added by `$http` so they aren't there when you create your own promise. You have two options:

### 1 - Don't mock the service and use `$httpBackend` to setup expectations and flush

The idea is to let your `myService` act like it normally would without knowing it's being tested. `$httpBackend` will let you set up expectations and responses, and flush them so you can complete your tests synchronously. `$http` won't be any wiser and the promise it returns will look and function like a real one. This option is good if you have simple tests with few HTTP expectations.

```
'use strict';

describe('SimpleControllerTests', function () {

    var scope;
    var expectedResponse = { name: 'this is a mocked response' };
    var $httpBackend, $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_){ 
        // the underscores are a convention ng understands, just helps us differentiate parameters from variables
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    // makes sure all expected requests are made by the time the test ends
    afterEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('should load data successfully', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
           $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1').response(expectedResponse);
           $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope });

           // causes the http requests which will be issued by myService to be completed synchronously, and thus will process the fake response we defined above with the expectGET
           $httpBackend.flush();
        });

        it('using loadData()', function() {
          scope.loadData();
          expect(scope.data).toEqual(expectedResponse);
        });

        it('using loadData2()', function () {
          scope.loadData2();
          expect(scope.data).toEqual(expectedResponse);
        });
    });

    describe('should fail to load data', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
           $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1').response(500); // return 500 - Server Error
           $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope });
           $httpBackend.flush();
        });

        it('using loadData()', function() {
          scope.loadData();
          expect(scope.error).toEqual('ERROR');
        });

        it('using loadData2()', function () {
          scope.loadData2();
          expect(scope.error).toEqual('ERROR');
        });
    });           
});
```

### 2 - Return a fully-mocked promise

If the thing you're testing has complicated dependencies and all the set-up is a headache, you may still want to mock the services and the calls themselves as you have attempted. The difference is that you'll want to fully mock promise. The downside of this can be creating all the possible mock promises, however you could make that easier by creating your own function for creating these objects.

The reason this works is because we pretend that it resolves by invoking the handlers provided by `success`, `error`, or `then` immediately, causing it to complete synchronously.

```
'use strict';

describe('SimpleControllerTests', function () {

    var scope;
    var expectedResponse = { name: 'this is a mocked response' };
    var $controller, _mockMyService, _mockPromise = null;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){ 
        $controller = _$controller_;
        scope = _$rootScope_;

        _mockMyService = {
            get: function() {
               return _mockPromise;
            }
        };
    }));

    describe('should load data successfully', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {

          _mockPromise = {
             then: function(successFn) {
               successFn(expectedResponse);
             },
             success: function(fn) {
               fn(expectedResponse);
             }
          };

           $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope, myService: _mockMyService });
        });

        it('using loadData()', function() {
          scope.loadData();
          expect(scope.data).toEqual(expectedResponse);
        });

        it('using loadData2()', function () {
          scope.loadData2();
          expect(scope.data).toEqual(expectedResponse);
        });
    });

    describe('should fail to load data', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
          _mockPromise = {
            then: function(successFn, errorFn) {
              errorFn();
            },
            error: function(fn) {
              fn();
            }
          };

          $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope, myService: _mockMyService });
        });

        it('using loadData()', function() {
          scope.loadData();
          expect(scope.error).toEqual("ERROR");
        });

        it('using loadData2()', function () {
          scope.loadData2();
          expect(scope.error).toEqual("ERROR");
        });
    });           
});
```

I rarely go for option 2, even in big applications.

For what it's worth, your `loadData` and `loadData2` http handlers have an error. They reference `response.data` but the [handlers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) will be called with the parsed response data directly, not the response object (so it should be `data` instead of `response.data`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would I test the error condition though? I'm starting to think using success and error explicitly outside the controller is really a bad idea. I'm thinking the controller code should be then(function(..success code here..), function(..error code here...) . Then I can simulate success \ error from the test using resolve() and reject() on the promise..

Comment: That's why option #2 sucks. If you want an error condition, move the `$httpBackend` setup and controller init into the body of the fact, or put it in it's own `describe` block that has the varied `beforeEach`. 

I'll update my example with success and fail.

Comment: OK, updated. Sorry if there are typos or small errors, I had to rush because a meeting just got called :p

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, this really got me thinking and I've decided that success and error have no place in my controller. Points to you though, you provided a perfectly workable solution. That dependency on the actual service implementation is something I'd rather avoid. Maybe I'm being too idealistic :)

Comment: At the end of the day, whatever you're comfortable with. But the way I've always looked at it, when dealing with external data, I'm testing a controller I want to make sure it's calling the service(s) to load or submit the data using the correct parameters when it's supposed to, and it's doing the right thing with the potential responses. Doing so by controlling it in one simple spot, `$httpBackend`, is the closest to the real thing while remaining practical and easy to implement in my tests. Again, it depends on what the service does, but truly and necessarily complicated services are rare.

Answer (score 3):

## Don't mix concerns!

Using `$httpBackend` inside a controller is a bad Idea since you are mixing concerns inside your Test. Whether you retrieve data from an Endpoint or not is not a concern of the Controller, is a concern of the DataService you are calling.

You can see this more clearly if you change the Endpoint Url inside the service you will then have to modify both tests: the service Test and the Controller Test.

Also as previously mentioned, the use of `success` and `error` are syntactic sugar and we should stick to the use of `then` and `catch`. But in reality you may find yourself in the need of testing "legacy" code. So for that I'm using this function:

```
function generatePromiseMock(resolve, reject) {
    var promise;
    if(resolve) {
        promise = q.when({data: resolve});
    } else if (reject){
        promise = q.reject({data: reject});
    } else {
        throw new Error('You need to provide an argument');
    }
    promise.success = function(fn){
        return q.when(fn(resolve));
    };
    promise.error = function(fn) {
        return q.when(fn(reject));
    };
    return promise;
}
```

By calling this function you will get a true promise that respond to `then` and `catch` methods when you need to and will also work for the `success` or `error` callbacks. Note that the success and error returns a promise itself so it will work with chained `then` methods.

### (NOTE: On the 4th and 6th line the function returns resolve and reject values inside the data property of an object. This is to mock the Behavior of $http since it returns the data, http Status etc.)

Comment: A little late to the party but I wanted to share my solution for this. Feel free to disagree with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do not use $httpbackend in your controller, because we don't need to make real requests, you just need to make sure that one unit is doing it's job exactly as expected, have a look on this simple controller tests, it's easy to understand

```
/**
 * @description Tests for adminEmployeeCtrl controller
 */
(function () {

    "use strict";

    describe('Controller: adminEmployeeCtrl ', function () {

        /* jshint -W109 */
        var $q, $scope, $controller;
        var empService;
        var errorResponse = 'Not found';


        var employeesResponse = [
            {id:1,name:'mohammed' },
            {id:2,name:'ramadan' }
        ];

        beforeEach(module(
            'loadRequiredModules'
        ));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_,
                                    _$controller_,
                                    _$rootScope_,
                                    _empService_) {
            $q = _$q_;
            $controller = _$controller_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            empService = _empService_;
        }));

        function successSpies(){

            spyOn(empService, 'findEmployee').and.callFake(function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(employeesResponse);
                return deferred.promise;
                // shortcut can be one line
                // return $q.resolve(employeesResponse);
            });
        }

        function rejectedSpies(){
            spyOn(empService, 'findEmployee').and.callFake(function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.reject(errorResponse);
                return deferred.promise;
                // shortcut can be one line
                // return $q.reject(errorResponse);
            });
        }

        function initController(){

            $controller('adminEmployeeCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope,
                empService: empService
            });
        }


        describe('Success controller initialization', function(){

            beforeEach(function(){

                successSpies();
                initController();
            });

            it('should findData by calling findEmployee',function(){
                $scope.findData();
                // calling $apply to resolve deferred promises we made in the spies
                $scope.$apply();
                expect($scope.loadingEmployee).toEqual(false);
                expect($scope.allEmployees).toEqual(employeesResponse);
            });
        });

        describe('handle controller initialization errors', function(){

            beforeEach(function(){

                rejectedSpies();
                initController();
            });

            it('should handle error when calling findEmployee', function(){
                $scope.findData();
                $scope.$apply();
                // your error expectations
            });
        });
    });
}());
```