# Angular/Jasmine: adding .error to callback seems to break unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I encountered an error that occurs only when I have the .error part of my http callback defined. Here is the relevant part of the controller I'm testing:

```
describe('SimpleControllerTests', function () {

    var scope;
    var expectedResponse = [{count:'101', time:1416960000000}];
    var $httpBackend, $controller, $timeout, uuid4;
    beforeEach(module('dashboardApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$timeout_,_uuid4_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $timeout =_$timeout_;
        scope = _$rootScope_;
        uuid4 = _uuid4_;
        spyOn(uuid4,'generate').and.returnValue("1");
    }));

    // makes sure all expected requests are made by the time the test ends
    afterEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(); 
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('should load data successfully', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
           $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost/folder/index', {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getData","id":"1","params":{"period":"week"}}).response(expectedResponse); 
            $controller('HomeCtrl as vm', { $scope: scope });
           $httpBackend.flush();
        });

        it('using dirtyTestGraph()', function() {
          scope.vm.dirtyTestGraph(); 
          $timeout.flush();
          scope.$digest();
          expect(scope.vm.chartData).toEqual(expectedResponse);
        });
    });

    describe('should fail to load data', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
                      $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost/folder/index',
            {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getData","id":"1","params":{"period":"week"}}).response(500);

           $controller('HomeCtrl as vm', { $scope: scope });
           $httpBackend.flush();
        });

        it('using dirtyTestGraph()', function() {
          scope.vm.dirtyTestGraph();
          $timeout.flush();
          scope.$digest();
          expect(scope.vm.chartData).toEqual('');
        });
    });
});
```

httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpecation fails on // <- Unsatisfied requests: POST http://localhost/folder/index

as does $httpBackend.expectPost in the beforeEach with: 'undefined' is not a function (near '...":"week"}}).response(expectedResponse);

it also appears that my scope isn't getting created properly, I get: 'undefined' is not an object evaluating 'scope.vm.graphLoading'

I use the 'controller as' syntax for declaring controllers, and i've used 'ctrl as vm' in other tests and i'm able to reference it fine, not sure what's going on there.

I forgot the controller method:

```
vm.dirtyTestGraph = function() {
            $timeout(function(){
                ChartService.get( { period: 'week'} )
                .success(function(res){
                    vm.graphLoading = false;
                    vm.chartData = res.data;
                }).error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }, 2000);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at this:

```
ChartService.get( {...} ).success(function(res){...}).error(function(err){...});
```

you will see, that you call error on "success", and not on "get", because you chained the functions

Comment: How so? ChartService.get returns a http.post() object. and the documentation says that you can chain methods like so: $http.post({}).success().error(); also, when i actually ran this code in the browser, the error method didn't get called but the success method did.

Comment: I mean your mock was not good for this purpose.
$http gives back a promise, your callback function is wrapped in that promise, that is why if a real request is not a success, the chain go through every promises and will reach the error part.
check this for your options: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731637/test-a-controller-with-success-and-error

Comment: I copied his entire 'option1' in the answer and I'm still not having any luck. I edited my main question to show the updated test